# Generalising typescript functions into one

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

i have a setup that looks like this:

```js
import { theme } from '../Theme'
import { select } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'

// Utility that returns object properties as a typed array seeing as Object.keys returns string[] :/
const keys = <O extends object>(obj: O) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>

const themeDefaults = {
  icon: keys(theme.icon), // returns something like: ['padlock', 'person', 'plus']
  color: keys(theme.color), // returns something like: ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary']
  size: keys(theme.size), // returns something like: ['s', 'm', 'l']
  margin: keys(theme.margin), // returns something like: ['s', 'm', 'l']
  padding: keys(theme.margin), // returns something like: ['s', 'm', 'l']
  radius: keys(theme.radius), // returns something like: ['s', 'm', 'l']
}

export const storyDefaults = {
  icon: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['icon'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.icon, defaultValue),

  color: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['color'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.color, defaultValue),

  size: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['size'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.size, defaultValue),

  margin: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['margin'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.margin, defaultValue),

  padding: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['padding'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.padding, defaultValue),

  radius: <T extends typeof themeDefaults['radius'][number]>(
    name: string,
    defaultValue: T
  ) => select(name, themeDefaults.radius, defaultValue),
}
```

Very conscious of the fact im repeating myself a lot and would love to convert this into one function. I tried the below but am getting a type error where im passing args into the `select` function

```js
const genericVersion = <
  K extends keyof typeof themeDefaults,
  T extends typeof themeDefaults[K][number]
>(
  key: K,
  name: string,
  defaultValue: T
) => select(name, themeDefaults[key], defaultValue) // <-- typeError
```

I think this might be down to the fact that im dynamically accessing a property in an object so TS needs more info about what i'm trying to do?

For easier debugging i have included a sandbox recreation of the type error: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-waterfall-7c91w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler isn't usually able to verify if values are assignable to types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters, especially when such types are [conditional types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).

The second argument to `select()` should be of the type `SelectTypeOptionsProp<T>`, defined like

```
type SelectTypeOptionsProp<T extends SelectTypeKnobValue = SelectTypeKnobValue> =
  Record<PropertyKey, T> | 
  Record<Extract<T, PropertyKey>, T[keyof T]> | 
  Extract<T, PropertyKey>[] | 
  readonly Extract<T, PropertyKey>[];
```

For your individual functions, this argument was always some concrete type like `("minus" | "plus")[]`, so the compiler was apparently able to verify assignability.  But in the generic function, the argument is of a generic type like `typeof themeDefaults[P]`, and the compiler gives up.  It *might* be able to verify that such a type matches a type like `T[]`, but `Extract<T, PropertyKey>[]` is beyond its abilities.

The easiest way to proceed for you is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that what you are doing is safe and that you're sure `themeDefaults[key]` acts like a valid `Extract<T, PropertyKey>[]`:

```
select(
  name,
  themeDefaults[key] as Extract<typeof themeDefaults[P][number], PropertyKey>[],
  defaultValue
);
```

You're only saying that all the elements of `themeDefaults[key]` are valid property keys, which the compiler can verify individually but not all at once.

---

Also, the `defaultValue` generic type in both your individual functions and your overall function is not really useful.  You're only using it in the input position and in one place.  A function signature like `<T extends Foo>(x: T, y: Bar) => Baz` can almost always be turned into `(x: Foo, y: Bar) => Baz` with no loss of expressiveness.  Therefore your `storyDefaults` should probably look like this:

```
export const storyDefaults = <P extends keyof typeof themeDefaults>({
  key, name, defaultValue
}: {
  key: P;
  name: string;
  defaultValue: typeof themeDefaults[P][number];
}) =>
  select(
    name,
    themeDefaults[key] as Extract<
      typeof themeDefaults[P][number],
      string | number | symbol
    >[],
    defaultValue
  );
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hellman-szjre)